# My Blender 2.79 crashes on Startup without loading the scene

Tags: windows, opencl

I've had a problem with Blender for about a week since installing it where every time I start up the program, it launches the output window, then begins to draw the window, but it doesn't create any of the interface before it just shuts down and closes altogether.

I had a similar problem with Autodesk Maya, and the solution to that problem was to disable OpenCL manually in the Maya.env file. Any idea as to how to fix this in Blender?

My PC specs are as follows:

- Windows 10 Home version 10.0.16299
- Intel Core i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 4 cores
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB GPU
- 8GB DDR4 RAM

I would add a picture of what the output window says as well, but It disappears and closes way too quickly for me to be able to catch it, and I don't know where to find the crash log or error report in my files.

Comment: Have you tried Blender 2.79b?

Comment: Yes, I have 2.79b currently installed on my pc.

Comment: Start Blender from a console window, maybe that'll give you more info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/introduction.html